# Signing PDFs using iTextSharp with certificate, reliable for at least 7 years

Tags: c#, security, certificate, pdf-generation, itext

I'm receiving files and I convert them to PDF/**A**. Then I want to sign them using an reliable signing method. What I try to achieve is the following.
The certificate...:

- will be applied on a self-made document (i.e. I have full control over the content)
- verifies the origin of the document (in this case, me)
- verifies there has nothing been changed (since the certificate/sign was applied)
- is reliable for at least 7 years (e.g. high quality algorithm)

This results in the following workflow.
**I generate a document. I put the sign/certificate on it. A user downloads the pdf from our website. Then he downloads the certificate I provide to verify the sign on the document. The result is that the sign is valid/invalid.**

The question is: *How to **Sign using iTextSharp** and **What do I need to get a certificate that is reliable for 7 years**?*

Edit: I've seen this document, but it gets me a little dizzy. There are so many options: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *reliable for at least 7 years?* **Do you mean that the signature shall verify as legally 'valid' for seven years?** In that case please explain the legal environment you are working in. Especially, does it require verification according to shell or chain validation. And which is the algorithm assessment catalogue relevant in that environment? **Or do you have different requirements for reliability?** In that case, please explain.

Comment: There are two possible ways of 'reliable': 1. The document remains the same since it was created on our server (even when downloaded 6,5 years later). 2. The document origin can be validated by a (public) certificate we provide, when the user downloads it. Either one of those should be contained in it.
Does this answer your question?

Comment: *Does this answer your question?* --- No. You don't say validation according to which rules shall be possible for the time. Is it validation according to some countries signature law? Which country's law? Or do you want to use self signed certificates and make your processes plausible to your recipients somehow?

Comment: It is mandatory for use with the Dutch laws of data archiving. We need to make sure the documents doesn't change the next 7 years. It's used for taxes for business and more like that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the specific Dutch signature law. Being in Europe, though, PAdES-4 should allow you to prolong validatability for many years.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need is a certificate that is valid for more than 7 years. You'll need a certificate that is stored on hardware (USB, HSM, smart card) and that is either CDS or AATL approved.

Even if you find a certificate that is valid for more than 7 years, you're not 100% sure it will remain valid during that period. Certificates can be revoked if they are compromised. For instance: when the person who signed the document loses his USB token. Signing using a Hardware Security Module should be more reliable.

As for algorithms: you should at least use SHA-2 and an encryption key of at least 2048 bits, but nobody will guarantee you that these algorithms will be safe for the next 7 years. In that sense, your question probably should be downvoted because it doesn't really make sense: you're expecting us to have a crystal ball.

However: if you read the final chapter of my book (the one that makes you dizzy), you'll see that it's always possible to extend the life of a signed document, by adding a Document Security Store (DSS) and a Document-Level Timestamp. That final signature (the Document-Level Timestamp) will typically use the most trusted algorithms of the moment. For instance: in a couple of years, you'll probably be able to use SHA-3.

Note that the type of signatures and the encryption algorithms also have an impact on the PDF/A version. Currently, you need at least PDF/A-2 for future-proof signatures.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll take all this in consideration. Especially the 7 year reliability and the possible problems with it.